# Can I install UbuntuTouch on a Billow tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, compatibility

My brand´s tablet is Billow (Billow x103Pro), and I want to install Ubuntu Touch on It. Can I do that although my device is not in the supported devices´s list?
Thanks!

Comment: We do not support hardware questions. if it does not work file a bugreport please.

Comment: You can try that is all anyone can tell you.

Comment: While I don't know if you can install Ubuntu touch, you can install a Ubuntu rootfs (with GUI) with Termux and VNC in almost any Android device (and it seems that this tablet has enough internal storage for a minimal Ubuntu installation).Check out https://www.fosslicious.com/2019/10/install-and-run-ubuntu-on-termux.html And of course, popular software like libreoffice, gimp can be used. *Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with any of these software*

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch can only be run on devices for which there are ports of Ubuntu Touch.

There's not port for that device. You can see the full and always updated list of existing ports/supported devices at the [Ubuntu Touch devices page](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io).